# when typing pip install (module) , a seamingly random window with another module that I once wrote (named cirkel.py), pops up, why does this happen?

Tags: pip

When installing or trying to use pip a window pops up (an old module named cirkl.py pops up that I wrote) this doesnt make sense to me. I have written both pip install followed by the module I wanted to install matplotlib and numpy. other commands with pip gives the same error. I have reinstalled pip, and changed the environment variables but, there's no change. I have also trying to locate the cirkl module but cant find it. I am using python 3.6

when closing the window I get this outpu from the cmd window:

in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "c:\users\matte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "c:\users\matte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "c:\users\matte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = **import**(self.module_name, fromlist=['**name**'], level=0)

..... etc

Comment: any advise on how to get pip to work would be very helpful.. :)..                                       it continues:  >
    from pip.commands import get_summaries, get_similar_commands
  File "c:\users\matte\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File..etc

Comment: if you open a python console, can you import cirkel?

Comment: yep, but I realized why i didnt find the module because i had another name for it than the name of the window. but importing the module actually draws a circle. strange ? makes me wonder.

Comment: and even though I have added the path it doesnt find it. thats also strange I have checked pip is there. to get the strange error I have to go to the catalouge.

Comment: I don't know how pip works exactly, but I've got to assume that it scans your currently installed packages, if you have written code that runs when it is imported (easy to do - pretty much if it is not in a function or class or `if __name__ == '__main__':` block it might run on import) that sounds like what is going on to me.

Comment: hm you're right that it's not in a function or class, but does that explain why ciirkel runs without being imported. I dont understand why pip would reference back to this module (or why it runs). do I have to clean up the environment variables. ( allthough I cant see what is wrong).  I am going to delete that module now and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think it's environment variables, I think that something in pip is testing / importing your module, and your module isn't import safe? Honestly this is past my understanding of pip - can you pip uninstall the module, or fix it so it doesn't have code that runs on import?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but no, I was wrong it was not the module I thought either. I changed the code but it still pops up and keeps the name of the window, even though I changed it in the module I thought it was. using (Zelle's Graphics) module.

Comment: yes you seem to be right, anyway I found the responsible module. but it was not the problem. I just had to write py -m install [module] . Thanks!